# xlutils package without attributes

Tags: python

I'm trying to use the xlutils package to deal with excel files with python, but
when I import this package and hit TAB (IPython) to see the attributes it's empty!

```
import xlutils
xlutils.  #hit tab here. Nothing appears.
```

I have the latest version of xlrd, xlwt and xlutils installed. Does anyone have any idea about this problem?

Thanks in advance,
Rhenan

Comment: Try `xlutils.__dict__`

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like they intend for you to use the modules within the package rather than the package root directly.

`help(xlutils)` gives a list of the modules inside that you can use.

`from xlutils import copy` gives you access to that functionality.

The help strings seem to point to the web so that's probably your best bet for help with it.

Answer (score 0):

It is very strange, I imported `xlutils` and `dir(xlutils)` gave me:

`['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package', '__path__']`

then I read the help string with `help(xlutils)`, it said:

```
PACKAGE CONTENTS
    copy
    display
    filter
    margins
    save
    styles
    tests (package)
```

and I tried to run this `import xlutils.copy` and the result of `dir(xlutils)` changed, so I believe you can autocomplete it after you import `xlutils.copy` or other contents you want.